# Decision Trees: Recommended Libraries

Tags: java, php, web-services, decision-tree

I want to know, if there are recommended libraries for decision trees.

For me best laguages atm are Java (easiest) and PHP (long term-usefulness).
I need them for a thesis at university and want to use the code later on as a webservice. The problem itself is not important and could be solved in various ways. But as a condition/constraint I have to use decision trees.

And I searched for quiet a while, but nothing really smashing turned up. So I decided to ask you.

As I said, Java would be easiest for me. And so would be Java-like languages (C++,...). PHP would be most useful as I want to use pieces of that code later on a server. Also frontend programming would be much easier ;-)
Other hosting-supported languages would be ok, too, but I'm not yet familiar with them.

The functionality doesn't need to be very complex as the problem isn't that based on decision trees. It would be nice if I could load the structure (kind of nodes, costs, units) via i.e. XML and than load a configuration-set with dedicated numbers for each node/transistion.

But I'm wondering, if it's maybe easier to implement that stuff myself.
I would be very pleased, if you can recommend something. (And for future investigators other languages wouldn't bother ;-) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look into the Weka API: https://weka.wikispaces.com/Use+WEKA+in+your+Java+code

They have an abundance of decision tree algorithms: ID3, CART, ...